# how to SFTP get file using cURL with PHP

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I am tryin to use the cURL library in PHP to SFTP get file from a remote server as follows. I get a `no such file exists` error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$user="username";
$pass="password";
$filename="/opt/vmstat/vmstat_file";
$c = curl_init("sftp://$user:$pass@server1/$filename");
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r') or die($php_errormsg);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

error:

```
Warning: fopen(="/opt/vmstat/vmstat_file): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sftp.php on line 9
```

Comment: are you sure sftp://$user:$pass@server1/$filename? or maybe better so sftp://$pass:$user@server1$filename ?

Comment: The code is correct as written. I suspect Occam's Razor is in effect... the file doesn't exist.

Comment: the file is definetely there.

Comment: Check the file ownership and permissions

Comment: the file as r permission for everybody.

Comment: you have var $filename="/opt/vmstat/vmstat_file"; when you use it here curl_init("sftp://$user:$pass@server1/$filename") become this curl_init("sftp://$user:$pass@server1//opt/vmstat/vmstat_file")

Comment: Your `fopen` call is asking for write permission. Do you have permission to write?

Comment: you need write permissions as well...

Comment: looks like cCurl is not able to connect to the server, I am not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$c = curl_init("sftp://$user:$pass@server1/opt/vmstat/vmstat_file");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
$data = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

this worked.

Comment: Are you saying this as a solution (i.e. no longer having the filename be a variable) or as a troubleshooting step (i.e. it works when you type out the filename yourself)?

Comment: Maybe the problem was the double slash in the question code. "server1//opt/vmstat/vmstat_file" != "server1/opt/vmstat/vmstat_file"

Answer (score 0):

Check the file ownership and permissions.
You're doing a `fopen($filename, 'w')`. Do you only want to be saying `fopen($filename, 'r')` instead?

Comment: I realized that error, changed it to r, still getting no file exist error.

Comment: Is the file on the remote server or on the box that youre running your code on? The fopen is trying to open the file on the local server

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're opening the local filehandle for reading.

```
$fh = fopen($filename, 'r') or die($php_errormsg);
```

I took your code and changed the 'r' to a 'w', and it works for me.